# Combobox returns an empty string instead of item with ID=0

Tags: javascript, user-interface, combobox, webix

I'm facing an issue with the Webix combobox: I have a dataset

```
{id:0, value:'Banana'},
{id:1, value:'Apple'},
{id:2, value:'Cucumber'},
{id:3, value:'Tomato'} //, etc.
```

But when I'm trying to set the first value as initial, the actual value stays empty, e.g.

```
{
   view:"combo", id:'combo',
   options:my_options,
   value:0
}
```

`getValue()` returns an empty string, but if ID is not `0` all works well. Anyone knows why this happens?

Here's the snippet http://webix.com/snippet/5d2f09db

Is there a workaround or I've missed something important?

Comment: Not sure why it won't work while having the Id's set to 0,1,2 but you can select them if you change to a,b,c... Maybe 0 returns false. Change the id's to something else and it will allow you to select the first option.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the combo value index starts from 1, try the following code.

```
var combo = webix.ui({
view:"combo",
options:[
{id:"0", value:'Banana'},
{id:1, value:'Apple'},
{id:2, value:'Cucumber'},
{id:3, value:'Tomato'}
],
value:0
});     

console.log(combo.getValue());
```

Comment: It definitely works, but I would like to know for sure is there a way to use `0` as ID or not, in my case it's quite important

Comment: it won't allow 0, it allows a string or a number which is greater than 0, if you want to make it work with 0 check the edited code above.